# Degree of time dilation for stars orbiting near Sagittarius A*?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, orbital-motion, time-dilation, stars

Sagittarius A* has an estimated mass of 4.154 million solar masses. A number of [stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittarius_A*#Orbiting_stars) have been found to orbit near Sagittarius A*.

What is the maximum time dilation factor for any of these orbiting stars (taking into account the mass of Sagittarius A*, but also the star itself, if possible)?

Does the amount of time dilation depend upon where in the elliptical orbit the star is, i.e. is time dilation maximized at the nearest point (the periapsis)?

Comment: The gravitational time dilation depends on the distance to the horizon in the units of the Schwarzschild radius. This is an easy calculation. +1

Comment: @safesphere Isn't that using the Schwarzschild solution? Wouldn't the Kerr metric be the relevant choice?

Comment: @AlexNelson You are correct, but in this case the difference is insignificant. The closest any star gets to Sgr A* is about 150 times its Schwarzschild radius. The time dilation there is minuscule.

Comment: This sounds a bit like a homework question.

Comment: @safesphere miniscule, but measured

Comment: @ProfRob Has it been measured?

Comment: @safesphere yes. By measuring/inferring the velocity of closely orbiting stars and measuring a redshift one can uncover the "components" of the redshift to test the GR prediction. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.09409.pdf

Comment: @ProfRob It's not a homework question. It's something I was wondering about for my own interest. I already tried to figure out how to calculate this, but I was out of my depth. It's not really fair that this was closed as a homework question when the question should in fact have general interest value. A lot of people became interested in gravity well time dilation after the movie Interstellar, and the case I asked about pertains to our own galaxy.

Comment: Rewrite the question so it isn't a homework-type question. The issue is not whether it is actually homework. e.g. Given the orbital parameters of a star around a supermassive black hole, how would I go about calculating the maximum level of time dilation expected?

Comment: @ProfRob I am bewildered that you don't see that that's basically exactly what I already wrote.

Comment: @ProfRob Thanks for the link, pretty cool! There is a clear trend in physics for the list of authors soon to become the largest part of the paper ;)

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/730794/time-dilation-in-an-elliptical-orbit